# Permissive sound file parsing library for iOS

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, core-audio, libsndfile

Does anyone know of any sound file parsing libraries with permissive licenses so as to be used on iOS, as an alternative to libsndfile?  Ideally I am looking for C/C++ code, but I would consider ObjC code as well.

I am fine with a library being less full featured as long as it isn't ensnared in l/gpl

So far searching has come up with nothing, any one know any gems?

Comment: Which file formats do you want to parse and why? Didn't you find something useful in the iOS SDK?

Comment: Its a music app.  Wave and Aiff are essential.  Broadcast wave (wave with metadata) would be be nice and anything else that might be included.  

Its mostly C++ so I have been avoiding the iOS SDK for most tasks, but if there is a soundfile parser that is not involved in audio playback that could potentially be used for the task.

Comment: What is the issue with using LGPL code in your app?

Comment: LGPL requires static linked code to either open source the code or provide the object files.  Its also questionably within the license, even then, should a law suit ever come up.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think through the iOS case.  But even if you provided object files how would someone relink a iOS app?

Comment: That is the rub.  There are currently a fair number of apps with LGPL components on the store but it was ever tested in court it could be bad.  Terrible the libsndfile is the only one out there - apparently he would change it if he could be there are too many people involved